# Text Field from right to left

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a input text feild,basically we will right from left to  right,i want modify such that, e.g if we multiply 23 x 2 , we will first write 6 then 4 to make it 46 .rather 4 first then 6,
it should appear as 46 only

Comment: i updated my ans check it ..I have done same in my project.it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `split(aString)` and `join(aString)`.
Convert the input string into an array, inverse it and then put it back into a string.

```
var textInput:String = input_txt.text;

var inputArr:Array=textInput.split("");
inputArr.reverse();

var reverseStr:String=inputArr.join("");
input_txt.text = reverseStr;
```

See an example here: http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/08/reversing-string-in-actionscript-3.html

Comment: Actually when inputting text it should reverse,And basically cursor  focus is  always right side,but i want the cursor  focus  should be in left side,Example Multiplication of 10X8,first will calculate one's place then tenth place i.e,  0 then 8 that so the answer is 80,

Comment: Ok, have you tried the `textAlign` property?

`input_txt.textAlign="right";`